# Cannot connect to server via SSH

Tags: mac, ssh

First time posting here. So I’m having some trouble connecting to a server on my home machine (Mac) via SSH. I can SSH into this server from work but at home I get a timed out error. Any thoughts on how I find out what’s causing this error?

Comment: Need more detail.  Are you getting any response back when you try to connect to this server via ssh?  Is there a firewall between you and the server?  Are there any firewall rules in place that only allow traffic to and from certain IP addresses?   Is the ssh server located at your house (that is how I am reading your question) or somewhere else?  Is the ssh server running on port 22 or some other port?   Do you have access to the firewall on the gateway where this ssh server resides?

Comment: Another thing to try would be a port scan from your work -> ssh server and also from home -> ssh server and post the results in your question.  I would suggest using nmap, but any port scanner would do.

Answer (score 0):

First of all check that you remote computer has a SSH server running.
After that make your that all the port forwarding are correctly configured.

If after these two steps you still have problems, maybe your local network has port 22 blocked.

I hope it helps you.